# Serial.read returning values that differ from the one in the Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino

Goal: I would like to prompt an integer from the serial monitor. These values will be used as part of a delay(value) command later on. The goal of this delay is to play two vibration motors slightly out of sync.

Issue: I'm trying to get values such as 60 or 400 from the command line. The current values do not match what is input.

My gut says this is a data format issue. I'm hoping someone can help me understand why each digit is printing as a number.

Prompt Subroutine Code:

```
  while (!Serial.available()) {       //this holds until we see a serial prompt
    } 
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    uint8_t inChar = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(inChar);
    // convert the incoming byte to a char and add it to the string:
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      receivedChar += (char)inChar;
    }

    // if you get a newline, print the string, then the string's value:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      Serial.print("Delay Value:");
      Serial.println(receivedChar.toInt());
      Serial.print("String: ");
      Serial.println(receivedChar);
      // clear the string for new input:      
    }
    newData = true;
    prompthold = false;
  }
}
```

Loop Code:

```
  void loop(){
    while (prompthold == false) {
      prompthold = true;

      Serial.println("Please enter delay");
      receivedChar = "";
      srl_prompt();
      apparentmotion();
    }

    delay(500);

  }
```

Diagnostic Info: 
Input of 1234567890

Returns:

```
16:28:13.079 -> 49
16:28:13.079 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.079 -> 50
16:28:13.079 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.079 -> 51
16:28:13.079 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.079 -> 52
16:28:13.079 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.079 -> 53
16:28:13.113 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.113 -> 54
16:28:13.113 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.113 -> 55
16:28:13.113 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.113 -> 56
16:28:13.147 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.147 -> 57
16:28:13.147 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.147 -> 48
16:28:13.147 -> Please enter delay
16:28:13.147 -> 10
16:28:13.147 -> Delay Value:0
16:28:13.147 -> String: 
16:28:13.147 -> Please enter delay
```

Input of 200

```
16:29:06.082 -> Please enter delay
16:34:02.121 -> 50
16:34:02.121 -> Please enter delay
16:34:02.121 -> 48
16:34:02.155 -> Please enter delay
16:34:02.155 -> 48
16:34:02.155 -> Please enter delay
16:34:02.155 -> 10
16:34:02.155 -> Delay Value:0
16:34:02.155 -> String: 
16:34:02.155 -> Please enter delay
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm pretty sure it's returning ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved this. If you use Serial.read() you get string/ASCII. If you use Serial.parseInt() you'll get a value. Updated code is below:

```
void srl_prompt() {
  while (!Serial.available()) {       //this holds until we see a serial prompt
    } 
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    uint8_t inChar = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(inChar);
    // convert the incoming byte to a char and add it to the string:
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      receivedChar += (char)inChar;
    }

    // if you get a newline, print the string, then the string's value:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      Serial.print("Delay Value:");
      Serial.println(receivedChar.toInt());
      Serial.print("String: ");
      Serial.println(receivedChar);
      // clear the string for new input:      
    }
    newData = true;
    prompthold = false;
  }
}
```